# FreeMarker creates a soap envelope variable

Tags: java, jboss, freemarker

I am new to FreeMarker language. What I am trying to do is to create a http request with soap envelope to grab the data back from the Third party server. I have a question about the "Escape sequence" in there.

For instance, I have a variable in my FreeMarker like

```
<#assign soap_env="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ns7:ClientInfoHeader soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns7="urn:messages.ws.rightnow.com/v1.1">
            <ns7:AppID>Run report sample</ns7:AppID>
        </ns7:ClientInfoHeader>
            <wsse:Security mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username>${login}</wsse:Username>
                    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">${Liu@8275?}</wsse:Password>
                </wsse:UsernameToken>
            </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header> <soapenv:Body>
    <ns7:RunAnalyticsReport xmlns:ns7="urn:messages.ws.rightnow.com/v1.1">
        <ns7:AnalyticsReport xsi:type="ns4:AnalyticsReport" xmlns:ns4="urn:objects.ws.rightnow.com/v1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ID id="146682" xmlns="urn:base.ws.rightnow.com/v1.1"/>
         </ns7:AnalyticsReport><ns7:Limit>1000</ns7:Limit><ns7:Start>0</ns7:Start>
    </ns7:RunAnalyticsReport> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope> ">
```

Do I need to replace all the quotation to another format? if yes, can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Freemarker Escape sequence        Meaning

  \"                         Quotation mark (u0022)
  \'                         Apostrophe (a.k.a. apostrophe-quote) (u0027)
  \\                         Back slash (u005C)
  \n                         Line feed (u000A)
  \r                         Carriage return (u000D)
  \t                         Horizontal tabulation (a.k.a. tab) (u0009)
  \b                         Backspace (u0008)
  \f                         Form feed (u000C)
  \l                         Less-than sign: <
  \g                         Greater-than sign: >
 \a                          Ampersand: &
\xCode                       Character given with its hexadecimal Unicode code (UCS code)
```

http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html

http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_escape.html

Answer (score 0):

If you meant the parts like `<#assign soap_env='<someXml someAttributes="someValue" />'>`, as you see right in this example, you should use two different quotation marks (`'` and `"`), so FreeMarker will not be confused about where the string literal ends. Or, you can use escaping too, like in `<#assign soap_env="<someXml someAttributes=\"someValue\" />">`, but that's uglier.